# code is not working properly while it worked very well last night with same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Last night I run the same code it worked but today is not working anymore.
the route is not working properly, '/' route is working properly but '/search' is not working.
I didn't change any of my code. why it's happening?

```
<Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/'>
            <div className='app__page'>
              <Sidebar />
              <RecommendedVideos />
            </div>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/search:searchTerm'>
            <h2>Search page</h2>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your routes configuration:

```
<Router>
   <Header />
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/'>
       <div className='app__page'>
         <Sidebar />
         <RecommendedVideos />
       </div>
     </Route>
     <Route path='/search/:searchTerm'>
       <h2>Search page</h2>
     </Route>
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: thank you so much brother. by the way, the code I am following is not using the exact path still his code is running but my code failing with the same code? and another question, yesterday I succeeded with that code, I didn't change any code. Today it's not working. What's the reason behind it?

Comment: I can't answer any of your questions, as I have no idea how the code you're following or your code of "yesterday" look like. Anyway, I seriously doubt that your very same code worked yesterday and stopped to work today. I can only suggest you go through the whole [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) docs, that would certainly help you understand what's happening in your app.

Comment: yeah, I agree. Thanks a lot anyway!